# Sending emails - how to?

Tags: java, android, email, dialog, feedback

So I managed to make the app to send an email but when inflating the dialog with the popup content the send button doesn't work anymore (i try to do a feedback when the user opens the app several times it shows him the popup whit some questions)

My mail code: it is inside (PopUp.java):

```
public class PopUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextSubject;
private EditText editTextMessage;
private Button buttonSend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);


    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

   //this is the button for sending the email
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void sendEmail() {
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

    sm.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendEmail();
}
}
```

this is my FeedBack.java(where I do the inflator for the dialog and count how many times the app was opened) and here is the problem (the dialog shows up whit every button/edit text ) but when I press the button it doesn't send the mail :

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private int totalCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed_back);
    prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    totalCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
    totalCount++;
    editor.putInt("counter", totalCount);
    editor.commit();



    if (totalCount == 2)
    {
       dialog();
    }

}

private void dialog() {
     final View viewPop = LayoutInflater.from(FeedBack.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up , null);


    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertBuilder.setMessage("Feedback!")
            .setView(viewPop)
            .setPositiveButton("Send!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  //i've tryed to call the function here but i dropped the idea because i didn't know how to call an method from another java file :(
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

And this is the code for sending the email :

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private String nume;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail( Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get a MessagingException?

Comment: i managed to do this :) @petey and i've posted how i did  below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works i put a call in `.setPosstiveButton` and in the method i did like this :

```
   private void sendMail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = editTextEmailValue.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubjectValue.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessageValue.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
}
```

and i've added this :

```
final View viewPop = LayoutInflater.from(FeedBack.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null);
    editTextEmailValue = (EditText) viewPop.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextSubjectValue = (EditText) viewPop.findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    editTextMessageValue = (EditText) viewPop.findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
```

in the dialog method

and declared :

```
private EditText editTextEmailValue;
private EditText editTextSubjectValue;
private EditText editTextMessageValue;
```